# Re-occurrence count

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the follow:

```
      Col1     
0      C        
1      A         
3      D         
4      A         
5      A
```

I would like to count the step/index that a certain value will re-occur so I would get the following:

```
      Col1      Col2  
0      C        NaN
1      A         2
3      D        NaN
4      A         1
5      A        NaN
```

Any ideas on how to do it ? Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then replace `0` to `NaN`s:

```
df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount(ascending=False).replace(0,np.nan)
print (df)
  Col1  Col2
0    C   NaN
1    A   2.0
3    D   NaN
4    A   1.0
5    A   NaN
```

Alternative solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount(ascending=False).mask(lambda x: x == 0)
```